# How to use wired function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm learning to write Lightning Web Components (and also rather a novice at modern javascript).

I'm trying to make the code on the LWC Developer Guide page [Handle Errors in Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_error) work. But when my callback is invoked, both data and error are undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
wiredRecord({error, data}) {
    debugger;
}
```

[image: Chrome developer tools debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that your component is not yet *constructed* and thus you are seeing the *default* values of the properties for a wired function, which happens to be `undefined`. If you let the component to be rendered, you should be able to view the values if you have appropriate access to the record.

This is documented in [Use the Wire Service to Get Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about):

> The property is assigned a default value after component construction and before any other [lifecycle event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks). The default value is an object with `data` and `error` properties of `undefined`
>
> ...
>
> The wire service provisions the function an object with `error` and `data` properties, just like a wired property.

Comment: Thank you Jayant! I just needed to ignore the first invocation and debug the second.

Answer (score 1):

The wire service first provisions the shape of the value: `{ data: undefined, error: undefined }`. This enables direct use of wired properties in the template to test for data and error. Eg `<template if:true={wiredProperty.data}>`. This is why you see said value provided to your wired function.

The wire service will invoked your method a second time, just give it time. You can check the network tab of Chrome devtools (or equivalent in your preferred browser) to see the status of the network request triggered by your `@wire`.

In terms of code structure:

1. You should check for `data` and `error` and respond accordingly. See [lwc-recipes' deleteRecord.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsDeleteRecord/ldsDeleteRecord.js#L18-L24) for an example.
2. The Lightning Data Service `@wire` adapters correspond to [UIAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) resources. Check out that doc site for the structure of the errors. The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_error) you reference are based on those resources' error structures.